# Selenium how do i get a href link embedded in a class without xpath?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: html for the example i'm trying]

I have a list of objects which are all of the class `div class="card"`. For each of these objects i want to get the web address under href. I can get it when i call the path, but when i try

`link = container.get_attribute("href")`
i get null. (container is the name of the current object in the list)

`link = container.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/a").get_attribute("href")`

This xpath method returns a link but it returns the same link every time and i'm trying to get it return the link for the container that it's in. I tried to get it with tags but keep getting doesn't exist errors.

Here is the full code

````
import yaml
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
address = "https://24slides.com/templates/most-popular"

# A set of all the titles of the templates from the site, and a dict with the title as the key and link as value
template_titles = set()
title_link_dict = {}

browser.get(address)
time.sleep(1)

# containers for the template on the site
containers = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("div.card")

# body of the page so that selenium can scroll down to load more templates
scroller = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

#number of times to scroll down
no_of_pagedowns = 1
time.sleep(1)

# scrolls down and appends all the new containers to the list of containers
while no_of_pagedowns:
    scroller.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    containers.append(browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("div.card"))
    no_of_pagedowns-=1

# TODO separate these into methods
# for each container, if it's a list then iterate through the list to get each element and then take the title
# and the link and add it to the dictionary after checking that it's a new entry (may not need to check since it's a
# dict). If it's not a list then do the same thing without having to nested iterate
for container in containers:
    if isinstance(container,list):
        for c3 in container:
            try:
                if set.__contains__(template_titles, c3.text):
                    pass
                elif c3.text == "":
                    pass
                else:
                    set.add(template_titles, c3.text)
                    link = c3.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/a").get_attribute(
                        "href")
                    trimmed_title = c3.text.splitlines()[0]
                    title_link_dict[trimmed_title] = link

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    else:

        try:
         if set.__contains__(template_titles,container.text):
            pass
         elif container.text == "":
             pass
         else:
            set.add(template_titles,container.text)
            link = container.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/a").get_attribute("href")
            trimmed_title = container.text.splitlines()[0]
            title_link_dict[trimmed_title]=link

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


print(len(containers))
print(len(template_titles))
print(len(title_link_dict))
print()

print(yaml.dump(title_link_dict))

time.sleep(10)

browser.quit()```
````

Comment: Of course `link = container.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/a").get_attribute("href")` will return the exact same link. It's an absolute path. You have to use path `//div[@class='card']/a` to get all links. I'm not familiar with Python but I think you have to use the `find_elements_by_xpath` function instead.

Comment: But i don't want a list of all of them, how do i write it so that it calls the href that corresponds to the card object i'm looking at in the for loop?

i have:

```containers = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("div.card")```

that's a list of "containers" which are basically the card objects. So what do i call within container to get the href link?

Comment: Try to change to `link = container.find_element_by_xpath("./a").get_attribute("href")`

Comment: This worked: ```container.find_element_by_css_selector('.card a').get_attribute('href')```

Thanks for the help. Do you know why i couldn't find it by tag name? Seems Requests with bs4 is a lot more useful because if i have an object and print it, it prints everything in the object instead of just a element id etc.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.